# Python: Choose textures in a sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sequence, python-2.x

I have a game which runs on python. It gets the texture for a powerup with the following line:

```
self.texture = bs.getTexture("texture1")
```

I want to edit it so that the texture being loaded changes in a sequence. Like for the first time powerup has texture1, second time texture2 and for the third time again texture1.

I tried to use random.choose but it becomes random and no sequence is followed.

Please tell me what should be written in place of this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [itertools.cycle()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
import itertools

sequence = ['texture1', 'texture2']
texture = itertools.cycle(sequence)

next(texture)
> texture1
next(texture)
> texture2
next(texture)
> texture1
next(texture)
> texture2
next(texture)
> texture1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus operation to loop back to the first index of the array.
Without using any extra libraries:

```
count = 0
sequence = ['texture1', 'texture2']
texture = count % len(sequence)
count = count + 1

# next_texture = count % len(sequence)
```